# Assigning check box values(totalling 3) to separate variables to pass into different columns

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is the HTML for the check box, I have a function that only allows three to be selected

```
<form class="interestSearchCriteria">
  <input type="checkbox" name="walking" value="Walking"> Walking
  <input type="checkbox" name="running" value="Running" > Running
  <input type="checkbox" name="hiking" value="Hiking" > Hiking
  <input type="checkbox" name="surfing" value="Surfing" > Surfing
  <input type="checkbox" name="powerkiting" value="Kiting" > Kiting
  <input type="checkbox" name="gym" value="GYM" > GYM
  <input type="checkbox" name="cycling" value="Cycling" > Cycling<br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="updateInterest">
</form>
```

Ajax call, I have three variables but how do i assign the first, second and third ticked values to each individual variable so I can send post to three separate columns?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#updateInterest', function() { 
    var firstInterest = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
    var secondInterest=$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
    var thirdInterest=$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/link",
      data: { 
        option1: firstInterest,
        option2:secondInterest,
        option3:thirdInterest          
      }   
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: u can send an array of selected values to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow up to 3 options to be selected, and also put the data into the correct option fields for the ajax call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#updateInterest', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default postback behaviour
    var valid = true;
    var data =  { option1 : null, option2 : null, option3 : null };
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(i, obj) {
      if (i < 3) {
        data["option" + (i+1).toString()] = this.value;
      }
      else { 
        alert("Please select up to 3 items");
        valid = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    
    if (valid == false) { return; }

    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //just to test
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/link",
      data: data
    });
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="interestSearchCriteria">
  <input type="checkbox" name="walking" value="Walking"> Walking
  <input type="checkbox" name="running" value="Running" > Running
  <input type="checkbox" name="hiking" value="Hiking" > Hiking
  <input type="checkbox" name="surfing" value="Surfing" > Surfing
  <input type="checkbox" name="powerkiting" value="Kiting" > Kiting
  <input type="checkbox" name="gym" value="GYM" > GYM
  <input type="checkbox" name="cycling" value="Cycling" > Cycling<br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="updateInterest">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#updateInterest', function() {
  var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

  var firstInterest = checked.eq(0).val();
  var secondInterest = checked.length > 1 ? checked.eq(1).val() : "";
  var thirdInterest = checked.length > 2 ? checked.eq(2).val() : "";

  console.log(firstInterest);
  console.log(secondInterest);
  console.log(thirdInterest);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="interestSearchCriteria">
  <input type="checkbox" name="walking" value="Walking"> Walking
  <input type="checkbox" name="running" value="Running"> Running
  <input type="checkbox" name="hiking" value="Hiking"> Hiking
  <input type="checkbox" name="surfing" value="Surfing"> Surfing
  <input type="checkbox" name="powerkiting" value="Kiting"> Kiting
  <input type="checkbox" name="gym" value="GYM"> GYM
  <input type="checkbox" name="cycling" value="Cycling"> Cycling<br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="updateInterest">
</form>
```

To select all checked checkboxes:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

To get first, second, third or any other index(say n):

```
.eq(n)
```